# Ruby on Rails - How to set the default ruby version in my project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I have a ruby on rails 5.2.4 app and in the: **app/site/shared/bundle/ruby** I have the following folders: **2.2.0** and **2.3.0**

In my: **app/site/current** , if I run: **ruby -v** it shows: **Ruby 2.2.3**

But if I run: **rvm use 2.6.6 --default** (or without default), the ruby version is changed, but on the next ssh connection the ruby version is 2.2.3 again. How can I add Ruby 2.6.6 to the **app/site/shared/bundle/ruby** folder and what should I change in order to remember the **ruby default version as 2.6.6**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:

create a file: **.ruby-version** in your app's `current` folder

Inside this folder add: **ruby-2.6.6** (or whatever ruby version you want to use as default).